# simple dart web app adding button very slow on IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, nginx, dart

creating the sample web app from dart editor, but changing the dart file to the following short code:

```
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
 querySelector('#sample_container_id').appendHtml('<button>Press</button>');
}
```

Then compiling to javascript.

Loading the html page in two separate ways: local file or through local web server (nginx).
Chrome and FireFox work perfectly.

IE local file also works perfectly.

But IE through nginx takes about one minute to add that button !!

Not sure whether this is a IE/nginx/dart(JS) problem or a IE/nginx problem.

Any help is appreciated.

As it is right now, I cannot even add one button to the DOM for IE users.
(also localfile on IE works, which suggests problem with nginx...maybe?)

Thanks,
Imran

Comment: Unless there's a massive amount of supplementary runtime code being loaded for the IE version, there's no reason that things should run differently when loaded from a local file vs. a server. The JavaScript won't even start until it's all in the browser.

Comment: Which version of IE? If you look at the network tab in IE's developer tools, what is the bottleneck?

Comment: @Juhana: I solved it...it was IE 11, but the problem was the loading of a dart script...I'll describe it in the answer below...but I got there by using the IE dev tools (didnt know that existed :)

Comment: Own answer: I figured it out when using IE dev tools:

When making a dart web app using the dart editor, the HTML loads the dart script and then a javascript, such that an equivalent javascript will run if dart is not supported by the browser.

Firefox and Chrome skip the dart script fast and load the javascript right away. But IE was trying for 1 minute to load the dart script.

A solution is to not load dart scripts for IE

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out when using IE dev tools:

When making a dart web app using the dart editor, the HTML loads the dart script and then a javascript, such that an equivalent javascript will run if dart is not supported by the browser.

Firefox and Chrome skip the dart script fast and load the javascript right away. But IE was trying for 1 minute to load the dart script.

A solution is to not load dart scripts for IE